# onDestroy called for Landscape activity A when Portrait activity B is opened from A

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-orientation, android-configchanges

I have an Activity A for which orientation (Portrait or Landscape) is set based on some condition. I have another activity B which is Portrait. Now when Activity A is in portrait mode and If I open Activity B then the activity A is not destroyed. But when the Activity A is in landscape mode and If I open Activity B then the Activity A's onDestroy() is called. And when I return back the activity's on create is called. I do not want this to happen. How to not call the onDestroy in activity A when moving from A(Landscape) to B(Portrait).I have attached the manifest below.

I am setting the activity A as landscape using

```
requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE
```

This is the manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".FirstChat"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="ABC"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:replace="android:icon,android:label,android:theme">

    <activity
        android:name="SplashActivity"
        android:label="APP"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Branch URI scheme -->
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityA"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityB"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent"/>
    
</application>
```

**Update on the question:**

The issue has been resolved I am putting this here so that if anyone else faces similar issue they can fix it the similar way. when I removed the below code from the manifest for ActivityB. Landscape Activity A stopped recreating itself when moving to Portrait Activity B

`android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent"/>`

Hence the Landscape Activity A stopped recreating itself when moving to Portrait ActivityB.

The reason was I was requesting landscape mode in activity A programatically and requesting portrait mode in activity B (tried both programatically and manifest orientation). Along with that I had also included the android theme in manifest for Activity B. This combined caused the activity A to destroy and recreate itself once again before going to Activity B. After removing the theme from manifest for Activity B now it works. Now I am setting the theme for ActivityB programatically in code. Everything now works fine.

**Note**: The above issue happens only when you set a theme in the manifest for activityB and forcefully set different orientation in the activityA and activityB

Comment: Hey, I've tested it and it doesn't happen to my example, could you show your manifest file please?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I have attached the manifest below. I have renamed the name of activities in manifest for you to understand. Please take a look.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. They're impossible to search in and to copy-paste from.

Comment: @Michael Got it.Thanks.

Comment: Still not happening, perhaps is something with the logic of your code

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Yes. I suppose it is. I just tried replicating it in a new project and it did not happen. Thanks for taking out your time.

Comment: Could you add your logic code?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS The issue has been resolved now. It was actually being caused by the theme in the manifest file combined with orientation set in the code. I removed the manifest theme and now it works fine :)